Prints finish before they actually are finished
The printer is finishing prints early. The printer notifies the print is finished but, in fact, it is not.

It is probably not a slicer error because I used the same settings for our other Ender 3 printer and it works.
I think it is not a motor error because I have printed a small frog to test it and it worked.

Any print that takes more than an hour seems to stop midway. It is normally halfway through the print and it stops at different points each time. When the print 'finishes' it just stops.
The nozzle is not clogged and the Bowden tube is not clogged. The print quality is great.
The person that had the printer before me must have messed something up. I have looked for others that had the same problem but haven't found any references.
What is causing the longer prints to finish prematurely?


Have you tried a different model and/or slicer? 2)Was the "small frog" a presliced model?


Are u printing from sd card or cable? maybe if you are printing from cable your pc has the sleep timer after 1 hour, so this is the problem...

If you search the web, you'll find that there are more people with these problems, where longer prints randomly stop mid-print, they date back a few years from now. Since returning the printer to the manufacturer is out of the question, I'd try the following to see if it helps.
First possible culprit could be a faulty SD card, so you could try to format the card or use another (new) SD card and try again.
Another possibility is that the controller board is getting too hot and shuts off, this could be related to a faulty controller board. You could try to open the bottom and force cool the board and see if this fixes the problem, or buy an upgrade controller board.
